# How to catch exception inside my do while loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, try-catch, do-while

My problem is that after the first exception is caught the variable `number` already has a value other then zero, so when the second exception is thrown. It just jumps out of my do-while-loop. I want to be able to catch two exceptions, or more depending on user input, without it jumping out of the loop.

Any thoughts? I'm new to coding so hope you can keep it simple :)

```
int number = 0;
int svar = 2; // set by the user; for example 2

do
{
    try
    { 
       for (int i = 0; i < svar; i++)
       {
           Console.Write("\nWrite the number you would like to add to your list: ");
           nummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       }

    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n-- ERROR --");
        Console.WriteLine("You typed a letter instead of a number, try again!");
    }

    myList.Add(number);

} while (number == 0);
```

Comment: Where does the second exception happen ?

Comment: `nummer` <> `number`. Really try to provide a real, compiling example of your code

Comment: Try using `int.TryParse(string, out int value)`  and a if statement to see if it was parsed successfully without having to catch an error. [Here's](https://dailydotnettips.com/back-to-basic-difference-between-int-parse-and-int-tryparse/) a good tutorial/ showcase of the differences

Comment: I would advice rewritting your logic and using TryParse instead manually handling the exception

Comment: Makes any sense now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! int.TryParse works, but I would like to understand the concept with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `int.TryParse`, see example below

```
 for (int i = 0; i < svar; i++)
 {
     Console.Write("\nWrite the number you would like to add to your list: ");
     while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("\n-- ERROR --");
         Console.WriteLine("You typed a letter instead of a number, try again!");
     }

     myList.Add(number);
 }
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks opewix That did the job, but i don't really follow the code...explanation? :)

Comment: @Japoc `int.TryParse` returns `true` when the string is a valid number, otherwise `false`. In `while` loop we wait for user input and try to parse it as a number. If we don't get a number we print a message to user and wait for user input again and again

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep the code *being simple* - let's *extract the method* `InputInteger`; another suggestion is to use `TryParse` instead of *exception catching*:

```
   private static int InputInteger(string title) {
     Console.WriteLine(); 

     // Keep on asking user
     while (true) {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title)) 
         Console.Write(title);

       // if correct integer value provided, return it
       if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var result)) 
         return result;

       // in case of syntax error print the message
       Console.WriteLine("-- ERROR --");
       Console.WriteLine("Please, type integer number, try again!");
     }
   }
```

Then you can use it whenever you want user input integer value:

```
   int svar = InputInteger("How many items would you like to have in the list?");

   ...

   // get svar integer items 
   for (int i = 0; i < svar; ++i)
     myList.Add(InputInteger("Write the number you would like to add to your list: "));
```

Comment: That's nice, you made a method out of the problem and then using it when adding to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use try block inside it like this

```
  int number = 0;
int svar = set by the user for exempel 2

do
{

       for (int i = 0; i < svar; i++)
       {
 try
  {
       Console.Write("\nWrite the number you would like to add to your list: ");
       nummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }

   catch
   {
   Console.WriteLine("\n-- ERROR --");
   Console.WriteLine("You typed a letter instead of a number, try again!");
   }

   myList.Add(number);

   }

} while (number == 0);
```

Comment: I had it like that in the first place, but it produced the same issue

Comment: Then you can reassign number to 0 in catch.

Comment: You mean I would put "number = 0;" after the error-message?

Comment: sadly it didn't work..I wrote "number = 0" and "i--;" after the error-message.

The loop works and it breaks the loop when user input is minimum 2 numbers, but afterwards when I try to print the list it only shows one of the numbers..

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you are new to coding. Welcome and I hope you are enjoying it.

I have refactored the code a little to make it simpler and error-free:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessNumbers();
        }

        private static void ProcessNumbers()
        {
            var myList = new List<int>();
            string sinput = String.Empty;
            var number = 0;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Write the number you would like to add to your list (type stop when you are done): ");
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();

                    if(input != "stop")
                    {
                        number = int.Parse(input);
                        myList.Add(number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sinput = input;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You typed a letter instead of a number, try again!");
                }

            } while (sinput != "stop");

            var sum = myList.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of all your numbers is: " + sum);
            Console.Write("Press any key to exist...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it will continuously ask user to keeping entering numbers until the user types stop. In the end, it will show the sum of all the numbers as a result. Let me know if you have any questions about the code.